# how to fix the problem of being unable to connect to the github server from eclipse IDE?

Tags: git, eclipse, github, ide, github-api

the issue Is That i Am Restricted from connecting eclipse IDE to the github server to apply push and merge request. The ERROR POP-UP is "CANNOT CONNECT TO the Github Server "

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to have A token to establish the connetion between the eclipse IDE and the github server.
after making the changes to your project and want to commit them, window for the URL github server and credential fields will pop-up. So:
first- generate a token. by going to Settings>Developer settings then click on Generate new Token.
second- copy the token and paste it in the password field instead your real password.
finnaly- commit the changes.
[hint] whenever the credentials is required during this process, you have to enter the user and renter the token as password.